# How to traverse JSON properties with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, elasticsearch

I am trying to access a particular property value of a JSON object with Powershell. Unfortunately I do not know the keys of some of the parent properties within the structure, so I cannot do this in a straightforward way. Also as the JSON is not an array I am unable to access via index position.

The context is that I am querying a list of running tasks from elasticsearch and need to get the ID of the task (I know that there will only be one) so I can make subsequent calls to discover its completion status.

I've researched some querying methods but am unsure on how to apply them (PowerShell syntax is quite new to me).

The JSON response I am working with looks like this;

```
  "nodes" : {
    "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A" : {
      "name" : "H5dfFeA",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "tasks" : {
        "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:124" : {
          "node" : "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A",
          "id" : 124,
          "type" : "direct",
          "action" : "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists[n]",
          "start_time_in_millis" : 1458585884904,
          "running_time_in_nanos" : 47402,
          "cancellable" : false,
          "parent_task_id" : "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this given structure, I would like to be able to access the ID property of the first 'task'.

So if I knew the prop keys it would be:

```
nodes.oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A.tasks.oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:124.id
```

How can I access this value without knowing the keys beforehand?

Any help very appreciated.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: In PowerShell 6 “-AsHastable”, can be used to deserialize directly to simple hastable type, which easily supports key enumeration. Don’t ask me why this wasn’t implemented years ago.. be aware however that there really IS “NO FIRST” OBJECT PER JSON and such should NOT be utilized for compatibility reasons. (An exception is for tooling maintaining human-preferred ordering, which is different from information interchange!)

Comment: Wrt. above: if the data is from an externals source, determine a more reliable method for “first” or other order.

Comment: @user2864740: While a hashtable representation to get the property names may be slightly easier, it isn't required: use `.psobject.properties.Name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code defines and uses **function `Get-FirstPropertyValue`**, which performs a **recursive, depth-first search for the first property inside an object graph that has a given name** and returns its value, assuming the value is non-null:

```
# Function that returns the value of the first property with the given 
# name found during recursive depth-first traversal of the given object.
# Note that null-valued properties are ignored.
function Get-FirstPropertyValue($obj, $propName) {
  $propNames = $obj.psobject.properties.Name
  if ($propName -in $propNames) {
    $obj.$propName
  } else {
    foreach ($iterPropName in $propNames) {
        if ($null -ne ($val = Get-FirstPropertyValue $obj.$iterPropName $propName)) {
          return $val
        }
      }
  }
}

# Input JSON
$json = @'
{
    "nodes": {
        "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A": {
            "name": "H5dfFeA",
            "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "tasks": {
                "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:124": {
                    "node": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A",
                    "id": 124,
                    "type": "direct",
                    "action": "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists[n]",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1458585884904,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 47402,
                    "cancellable": false,
                    "parent_task_id": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

# Convert the JSON to a [pscustomobject] graph with ConvertFrom-Json.
$objFromJson = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Using the function defined above, get the first 'tasks' object found
# during recursive depth-first traversal.
$tasks = Get-FirstPropertyValue $objFromJson 'tasks'

# Get the name of the resulting object's first property.
$propName = @($tasks.psobject.properties.Name)[0]

# Extract the .id property from the object stored in the first property.
$tasks.$propName.id
```

The above yields:

```
124
```

---

A **more concise, but more obscure and presumably slower alternative** is to **convert the JSON input to XML and then use *XPath*** to query it:

```
# Input JSON
$json = @'
{
    "nodes": {
        "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A": {
            "name": "H5dfFeA",
            "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "tasks": {
                "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:124": {
                    "node": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A",
                    "id": 124,
                    "type": "direct",
                    "action": "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists[n]",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1458585884904,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 47402,
                    "cancellable": false,
                    "parent_task_id": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

$parent = 'tasks'
$prop = 'id'
$propType = 'int'

$json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
    ConvertTo-Xml -Depth ([int]::MaxValue) | 
      Select-Xml "//Property[@Name='$parent']/*/*[@Name='$prop']/text()" |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerText -as $propType }
```

Comment: thank you I have this working :0 although I had to allow for the element not to be there, in which case the above method recursed forever, so I put a limit on max recursions which is fine for my use case.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Grenville. Since I'd like to fix my `Get-FirstPropertyValue` function if it has a problem: I don't see it recursing indefinitely when given a non-existent property name. Can you elaborate on when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of that you can achieve this, both look a bit gnarly.

For these examples, I will load the JSON you have provided into `$json`.

```
$json = @'
{
    "nodes": {
        "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A": {
            "name": "H5dfFeA",
            "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "tasks": {
                "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:124": {
                    "node": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A",
                    "id": 124,
                    "type": "direct",
                    "action": "cluster:monitor/tasks/lists[n]",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1458585884904,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 47402,
                    "cancellable": false,
                    "parent_task_id": "oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A:123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The first is to use `Select-Object` to select the first item and then expand the properties.

```
(($json.nodes | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty *).tasks | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty *).id
```

A more robust method, is to use the hidden PSObject property `Value`, as the JSON is parsed by PowerShell into a PSCustomObject.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $json.nodes.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                      
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

The Properties of `.PSObject`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $json.nodes.PSObject.Properties


MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : @{name=H5dfFeA; transport_address=127.0.0.1:9300; host=127.0.0.1; ip=127.0.0.1:9300; tasks=}
TypeNameOfValue : Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name            : oTUltX4IQMOUUVeiohTt8A
IsInstance      : True
```

The full command to access the ID value:

```
$json.nodes.PSObject.Properties.Value.tasks.PSObject.Properties.Value.id
```